# JDBC Sqlite trying to get Nullable Columns

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve all nullable columns from an `SQLite Database` in Java.

I don't know why `JDBC` is returning that only the primary key is `Not NULL` when there are two columns with `not null`property.

```
CREATE TABLE `univDB` (
        `x` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `FirstColumn`   TEXT NOT NULL,
        `SecondColumn`  TEXT
    );
```

and when I run the following code:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table);

    for (int i=1; i<= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("NULLABLE column "+i+" "+rs.getMetaData().isNullable(i));
            if (ResultSetMetaData.columnNoNulls == rs.getMetaData().isNullable(i)) {
                System.out.println("Column Not Null "+rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            }
     }
```

I get that `x` is the only non-nullable column of the `DB` but there should be `FirstColumn` too.

Comment: If you are trying to fetch not null columns in each row, shouldnt your for loop run for number of rows in the tables:

 for (int i=1; i<= rs.getMetaData().getRowCount(); i++)

Comment: No, I am trying to retrieve columns that allow or not allow nullable values.

Comment: Looks like a bug (or missing feature) in your JDBC driver (whatever it is).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with sqlite version `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2`

You can try this instead (source: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))):

```
try {
    DatabaseMetaData meta = dbConn.getMetaData();               
    ResultSet rs_columns = meta.getColumns(null, null, table, null);                    
    while(rs_columns.next()) {
        String columnName = rs_columns.getString(4); // Columnname
        String nullable = rs_columns.getString(18); // Nullable returns smth like "NO" or "YES"
        System.out.println("clmn: " + columnName);
        System.out.println("IsNullable: " + nullable); 
    }

    // OR directly
    String columnName = "A_CLMM_NAME";
    ResultSet rs_column = meta.getColumns(null, null, table, columnName);                   
    if(rs_column.next()) {
        String nullable = rs_column.getString(18); // Nullable
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```