# Return the names from columns in sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to perform an sqlite query in java code which will return the columns names from an sqlite table. How can I do so? I am only managed to get the values from the table and not the names of the columns.

Comment: You can also achieve this with `DatabaseMetaData`: [JDBC Sqlite trying to get Nullable Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172550/jdbc-sqlite-trying-to-get-nullable-columns/39370248#39370248)

Answer (score 3):

Use "select ... limit 0" query to get just metadata, then use ResultSetMetaData objects to actually retrieve it. Something like this:

```
List<String> sqliteTableColumns(Connection connection, String tableName) {
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from " + tableName + " LIMIT 0";
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData mrs = rs.getMetaData();
    for(int i = 1; i <= mrs.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        columns.add(mrs.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    return columns;
}
```

Comment: Is it normal in sqlite browser that I am not getting anything after performing this query: select * from  tableName  LIMIT 0?

Comment: @konstantin yes, it's normal, because due to "LIMIT 0" select return zero rows. The LIMIT clause is used to place an upper bound on the number of rows returned by the entire SELECT statement.